# Generate a random number NOT divisible by x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

I'm using `rand(1..10) * 3` to generate a random number divisible by three.

Is there a simple way to generate a random number that's **NOT** divisible by three (or any other number) without having to sample from an array?

Comment: The easiest way is to check if the generated number modulo 3 is 0, and if so re-generate. Pseudo code: `while((x = generate_random % 3) != 0)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
k = rand(0..1000)
out = k + k/2 + 1 # The '/' here is integer division.

0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 5
4 -> 7
5 -> 8
6 -> 10
...
```

Comment: Much better than using a loop, +1.

Comment: This is possible because an int divided by an int is rounded down, not expressed as a float. This only handles the case of "by 3", but the same principle could remap arbitrary numbers.

Comment: To complete this answer for any `N>1` (i use math symbols, i do not know ruby very well): `out = ⌊(k-1)*N/(N-1)⌋ +1`. (the `k-1` can be replaced with `k`, if it is OK to become `1` for `k=0`) (do not work for k<0).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
y = 3
x = nil
loop { break if (x=rand(1..10))%y !=0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int getNumberNotDivisibleBy9()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randm;
    randm = rand();
    while (randm % 9 == 0)
        randm = rand();
    return randm;
}
```